# Unable to play 3gp file in iOS

Tags: ios, avplayer, mpmovieplayer

Could someone help me on this.

Apple documentation say that we can play 3gp media file using iOS media player.
I have tried `MPMovieController` and `AVPlayer` but i'm unable to play.

Comment: In which doc you saw 3gp ?

Comment: 3gp is supported, but make sure your 3gp matches the apple standards. (resolution and fps etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the system `AudioToolbox.framework` for playing sounds in my simple game. I added this static function to common MyGame class:

```
+ (SystemSoundID) createSoundID: (NSString*)name
{
  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@",
                     [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], name];


  NSURL* filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path isDirectory: NO];
  SystemSoundID soundID;
  AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
  return soundID;
}
```

I added the "Morse.aiff" file to project Resources and initialized it in (any) class initialization with the following:

```
self.mySound = [MyGame createSoundID: @"Morse.aiff"];
```

And then I played sound with this call:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
```

Also, don't forget to import `AudioServices.h` file.

This audio toolbox can play also different sound formats.

Hope it may help u..